# Tish'a Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yitzchok Avinu was 179 when the Sar Ha'Mashkim and Sar Ha'Ofim had their dreams interperted by Yosef.

Yitzchok = 179

Yaakov = 119

Yosef = 28

Yosef became the Mishne L'Melech when he was 30 years old thus 2 years earlier he interperted the dreams.

Answer (score 3):

*Kenan* lived until *Noach* was 179. (*Mahalal'el* was 65 at *Yered*'s birth, *Yered* 162 at *Chanoch*'s, he 65 at *M'sushelach*'s, he 187 at *Lemech*'s, and he 182 at *Noach*'s. That's 661 of the 840 years *Kenan* lived after *Mahalal'el*'s birth, leaving 179.)

Answer (score 2):

The [1939 white paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Paper_of_1939) passed the House of Commons with 179 nays to the 268 ayes.

Answer (score 1):

[Supposedly (but I have no good source)](http://books.google.com/books?id=JlqjTTlHMjoC&pg=PA652&dq=elohim), אלקים appears in 179 verses of בראשית‎.

Answer (score 0):

[Supposedly (but I have no good source)](http://books.google.com/books?id=_VpIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA186&dq=memra), מימרא דה׳‎ appears in אונקלוס‎ 179 times. Perhaps someone has a script that can check this.